# structure in C,check if the dot is in the circle

Tags: c, structure

Hi I try to write a code but it shows me that there is a error but I dont see any errors, the code must get from user  coordinates of X and Y and R-radius of circle, that the second coordinates of X and Y and use function to check if the secont dot is in the circle.

```
    typedef struct point
    {
    float x;
    float y;
    }point;

     typedef struct round
     {
        int R;
    point dot2;
     }round;

    int is_in_cir(point, round);

      int main()
      {
        int ans;
        point dot1;
        round cir;

        printf("Please enter the coordination of the radius: \n");
            scanf("%d", &cir.R);
          printf("Please enter the coordinates,x and then y:\n");
            scanf("%f", &cir.dot2.x);
        scanf("%f", &cir.dot2.y);

      Printf("Please enter two more coordinates to check if the dot is in                the circle\n");
            scanf("&f",&dot1.x);
            scanf("%f",&dot1.y);

            ans = is_in_cir(dot1, cir);
            if (ans)
            printf("The dot you entered is in the circle");
            else printf("The dot you entered isnt in the circle");

            _getch();
            return 0;
             }


int is_in_cir(point a, round b)
{
double ans;
ans = sqrt(pow((b.dot2.x - a.x), 2) + pow((b.dot2.y - a.y), 2));
if (b.R >= ans)
    return 1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who is it (showing you an error)? What is the error? If it's per a specific input what is that input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scanf where you've put &f instead of %f

```
scanf("&f",&dot1.x);
```

Comment: Thank you, allso I used the word 'round' and this is illigle